# expected ';' before '{' token C code

Tags: c, debugging

I am getting the above error. I am coding in C and using standard gcc compiler (command window). Here is the part of my code that is given problematic. I do not see any errors, perhaps my eyes are tired of looking at the same thing

```
LEADER *call_leader(double st1, double st2, double incentive, double pdis)
{
    LEADER *leader= (LEADER *)malloc(sizeof(LEADER));
    double shortest = MIN(st1, st2) ; //shortest station
    if (shortest == st1 && s1 != 0){ //no congestion
        leader->price1 = p_max;
        leader->price2 = p_max;
    }

    if (shortest == st2 && s2 != 0){ //no congestion
        leader->price1 = p_max;
        leader->price2 = p_max;
    }

    if (shortest == st1 && s1 == 0){ //congestion at station 1
        if (s2 != 0){ // no congestion at station 2, try to route
            leader->price1 = p_max;
            double cost_1 = shortest*pdrive + p_max;
            double p2 = cost1 - st2*pdrive - (sqrt(pow((st2 - st1),2)))*pdis -     incentive;
        if (p2 >= p_min){
            leader->price2 = p2;
        }else{
            leader->price2 = p_min;
        }
    }
    else if (s2 == 0){
        if (r1 >= r2){ // st1 less congestion
            leader-> price1 = p_max;
        }
Problematic Line =>     else (r1 < r2) {   //try to route s2
            leader -> price1 = p_max;
            double cost_1 = shortest*pdrive + p_max;
            double p2 = cost1 - st2*pdrive - (sqrt(pow((st2 - st1),2)))*pdis - incentive;
            if (p2 >= p_min){
                leader->price2 = p2;
            }
            else{
                leader->price2 = p_min;
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: `else` doesn't take a conditional statement, you probably meant `else if (r1 < r2)`.

Comment: I've fixed your formatting. But for future reference, try to avoid using tabs in the code blocks as they can mess up the formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a condition for `else`. It's executed when conditions on all `if`'s fail. Remove stuff if parentheses and you'll be fine.:

```
else {
...
```

Answer (score 3):

`... else if (r1 < r2) ...` would be the conditional form of the statement, but as the fist `if` had a complementary condition `(r1 >= r2)` a simple `else` does it.

So you will have:

```
if (r1 >= r2){
    leader-> price1 = p_max;
}
else {
    leader -> price1 = p_max;
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
else (r1 < r2) {   //try to route s2
```

to

```
else if (r1 < r2) {   //try to route s2
```